# How can we use UUID in Django with django-haystack?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-haystack

When I had a model with UUID field as a primary key, django-haystack was unable to search for the model text field.
When I looked into the code of django-haystack (query.py), I found out that in the result post-processing primary key is validated as integer.
i.e.:

```
result.pk = int(result.pk)
```

This I guess is the reason behind the problem. Has anyone looked into it? Is there a solution or workaround to it?

Comment: https://github.com/django-haystack/django-haystack/issues/399

Comment: Did you try using http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/v2.4.0/settings.html#haystack-identifier-method ?

Comment: Will give it a try, thanks